# How to use AngularDart with payment request API? or does the payment request API exclusive to Javascript?

Tags: dart, progressive-web-apps, angular-dart, payment-request-api

Usually payment request API being used with Javascript, is there any example on how to use payment request API with AngularDart? as for now i never seen someone using it which make me think is that possible. Or does the Payment Request API intended to be used by only javascript?

Answer (score 0):

So Dart can call any JS in the browser using package:js https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js

In terms of GoogleUIs it is pretty easy to generate the RPCs in a couple of different languages using: https://github.com/dart-lang/discoveryapis_generator

Here are some examples that are made with that: https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis